# Implications of solubility of equations modulo all natural numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Let $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0$ be a given polynomial Diophantine equation in $n$ variables with integer coefficients (for example $x_1^2+3x_2-10+x_1x_2^4=0$).

Suppose further that this equation has a solution modulo every natural number $m$. That is for every natural number $m$ we can assign integer values to $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ such that $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is divisible by $m$.

Does this imply that the equation $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0$ has integer solutions?

(Clearly having a solution modulo every natural $m$ is a necessary condition for $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0$ having solutions. I'm interseted if it is also a sufficient one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an extreme example, use $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+1=0$. There are solutions modulo every $m$, but no integer solutions.

It is useful to add the condition that there are real solutions. There is a large literature. For details, look under *Hasse Principle*.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I assume that the intended argument for the above equation having a solution modulo every $m$ is the Lagrange's four square theorem? If it isn't is there perhaps as easier way to see this?

Comment: Thanks also for the literature pointer. Will look into it.

Comment: Yes, the reason I chose it is the four-square theorem.

Comment: So if one adds the condition that the equation must be soluble in the real numbers then the condition from the question is also sufficient? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: It isn't, but for quadratic forms it is. Already with cubic forms in $3$ variables there is a problem with $3x^3+4y^3+5z^4=0$. Famous example. I think it was due to Selmer.

Comment: Apologies, typo above, it is $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$.